# How to get rid of an in game ad banner that covers up gameplay?

Tags: ios, android, star-wars-tiny-death-star

I recently got an in-game advertisement banner which covered the menu/x button, credit total and bux total. I tried clicking on it, but it only opens a web page and the ad stays in view.

With other ads like the Lego Movie ad, it usually vanished after exiting the "Behold! while you were away" screen.

How can I get rid of this annoyingly-placed ad?

Answer (score 1):

Here's some things to try:

- Some ads can be dismissed with an 'X' in one of the corners. Unfortunately, depending on the implementation, this may leave a blank spot where the ad was, which may still 'cover' up gameplay.
- Some ads may have a 'Skip' button (usually very small) which will close the ad (thanks David M!)
- Some full-page Ads can be dismissed by pushing the 'back' button on Android devices.
- You might be able to clear the ad temporarily, by killing the process on your phone and reloading it. (thanks user66184!)
- For games that allow offline-play, try turning off Wifi and Mobile data - a lot of games don't cache ads locally and thus the ads just don't appear because they can't be downloaded. (thanks DrakaSAN!)

Note that sometimes the ad placement covering game elements may be due to a glitch. Closing and reopening the game may cause the ad to be properly placed and/or dismissible again.

Comment: This answer was mostly compiled from comments left under the question (and thus I have made it community wiki). Also note that the OP (Jen) updated their question to state that the ad disappeared on it's own.